# Two-Sample Problem Questions

Tags: self-study, t-test

I'm just preparing for my exam, but I have no idea how to solve this problem:

> Durable Press cotton fabrics are treated to improve their recovery
> from wrinkles after washing. Unfortunately, the treatment also reduces
> the strength of the fabric. A study compared the breaking strength of
> fabrics treated by two commercial durable press processes. Five
> swatches of the same fabric were assigned at random to each process.
> Here are the data, in pounds of pull needed to tear the fabric.
>
> Permafresh: 29.9, 30.7, 30.0, 29.5, 27.6
>
> Hylite: 28.8, 23.9, 27.0, 22.1, 24.2
>
> Test the hypothesis null hypothesis U1 = U2 against the two-sided
> alternative twice: once using all the data and again without the
> outlier in the Permafresh sample. Do the two tests lead to similar
> conclusions? Can we safely conclude that one treatment has
> significantly higher mean breaking strength than the other?

Help would really be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: This seems to be a standard textbook question. Please read the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag wiki info, add the tag and then let us know what you already understand, what you've tried, and so on.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @James, but we treat them differently (please read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)): tell us what you understand & where you're stuck, & we'll provide some hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: This textbook question appears to be encouraging p-hacking? If you cannot explain the outlier as data entry error what is the justification for dropping it?

Comment: One might use the t-test; perhaps the Welch-Satterthwaite version

Comment: A permutation test could also be considered.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, one might use the (Welch) t-test.
[Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test)'s t-test is recommended when we don't have the assumption of equal variance.

In Python you could do this as follows:

```
from scipy import stats
Permafresh = [29.9, 30.7, 30.0, 29.5, 27.6]
Hylite = [28.8, 23.9, 27.0, 22.1, 24.2]
print(stats.ttest_ind(Permafresh,Hylite, equal_var=False, alternative="two-sided"))
```

For the second part of the question, it may be interesting to consider the point raised in the comments - if the point is not a data entry error, for what reasons are we justified removing it as an 'outlier'. In a real analysis you would consider this.

For 'fun' (boredom), I plotted the boxplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.boxplot([Permafresh,Hylite])
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot]

In the case above, using matplotlib to plot the box plot, outliers are considered as any points beyond the whiskers. That is, $Q3 + 1.5 IQR$. Of course, what is considered an outlier is often subjective and data specific. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622490/are-points-beyond-box-plots-whiskers-outliers).

---

For the t-test, you might like to think about the normality assumption and whether it (roughly) holds. Perhaps the full wording of the question mentions something about this though, for brevity in the answer I will assume it does.